# Unity UI scale with screen size works fine on unity but on android phone

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I am trying to make an AR app on unity and all works fine. Only problem is auto screen scale works fine in game mode on any screen of unity but when I install in into my android note 3, does not scale screen well. Buttons are out of screen. Appreciate for any suggestions...

Comment: Please be more descriptive than "Does not scale screen well". Also, "why doesn't this code work" type questions need to include at least enough code to reproduce the problem. This question should be closed until enough information is provided to give an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Canvas to be "Scale With Screen Size".
[image]
More information here- https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-CanvasScaler.html